# How to get max count for a loop in channel entries tag

Tags: categories, entries, loop, count

I am trying to get the max results for the categories inside this channel entry. If the current category is the last one in the loop I don't want to add a , after the output.

```
   {exp:channel:entries channel="ch_efn_gallery" entry_id="295"}
    {categories}
            {"{category_id}":"{category_name}"}
           {if categories:count!=categories:total_results},{/if}
    {/categories}
   {/exp:channel:entries}
```

*categories:count* gives me the correct number. But *categories:total_results* doesn't work. And i din't find out how to get the max value for categories. Actually this template has much more output but i shortened it to the core of my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by using php. First i go through all of the categorys and count them. after that i check it with another variable where i count the current Category.

```
[
{exp:channel:entries channel="ch_efn_magazin" entry_id="304"}
    {
     "ID": "{entry_id}",
     "Category": [{
        <?php $maxCat = 0; $currentCat = 0; ?>
        {categories}
           <?php $maxCat++; ?>
        {/categories}

        {categories}
          "{category_id}":"{category_name}"<?php $currentCat++; if($maxCat != $currentCat) echo(','); ?>
        {/categories}
        }]
 }
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

The whole reason I am doing this, is to create a JSON file. I know that there is this [Json Plugin by Rob Sanchez](https://github.com/rsanchez/json) but with this plugin I wans't able to loop through my Channel_Images. That's why I decided to do it like this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and simply use the [backspace tag](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/categories.html#backspace)

Assuming it's that straight forward. I've never really liked the EE categories tag, I lean towards [GW Categories](http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories/documentation). You can then disable categories in your main loop to save some overhead.

Comment: {categories style="linear" backspace="1"} does not work.

and i am using 2.9 that's why at the moment ints not possible for me to use GW Categories...

Comment: What, GW doesn't work on 2.9?

Comment: i'm sorry, i red it wrong. it's possible to use it. but i was able to fix my problem with php.

Comment: For the record, php in this context is a bad idea. Pls post your solution as an answer

Comment: I know that my solution is kinda ugly, because I am using php. But I didn't saw another way to do it. I posted my solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

[GW Categories](http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories/documentation) is free, but for EE1 and EE2 only - do something like:

```
{exp:gwcode:categories entry_id=“295" style=“linear” backspace=“1"}
{cat_id}:{cat_name},
{/exp:gwcode:categories}
```

If you want to work in EE3 (or plan to) you could use [Category Construct](https://buzzingpixel.com/software/category-construct/documentation/template-tags) as a direct replacement - though currently the ‘backspace’ feature in Category Construct is broken.